# How can I sort a List<T> by multiple T.attributes?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Let's say I have a List of Songs.

```
Song {
    public string Name = "";
    public int PlayOrder = 0;
    }
```

Now I want to sort them first by PlayOrder starting at zero and second by Name alphabetically.

So an example set of sorted results would be (Name, PlayOrder):

```
/*
    Pachelbel's Canon, 0
    A Happy Song, 4
    Beethoven's 5th, 4
    Some Other Song, 7
*/
```

See how the PlayOrder = 4 ones are in order alphabetically? That's what I'm going for.

Right now I have it only sorting by one field:

```
List<Song> final = new List<Song>();

...

final.Sort((x, y) => x.PlayOrder.CompareTo(y.PlayOrder));

return final;
```

How can I also sort by Name as demonstrated above?

Answer (score 102):

```
return final.OrderBy(s => s.PlayOrder).ThenBy(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: Note that this returns a new `IEnumerable<Song>` sequence rather than sorting the original list in-place.

Comment: If I wanted it to return a List could I tack a .ToList() onto the end there?

Comment: In your other comment where you state that OrderBy performs a stable sort, you described what a stable sort meant. Could you also explain the unstable sort using the same example?

Comment: her is a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615100/order-of-list-using-linq-is-not-the-same-as-sort

Comment: Ooooooh use THENBY - but of COURSE!!!  Man I need to RTFM more often :)

Answer (score 50):

If you want to continue using the sort method you will need to make your comparison function smarter:

```
final.Sort((x, y) => {
    var ret = x.PlayOrder.CompareTo(y.PlayOrder);
    if (ret == 0) ret = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    return ret;
});
```

If you want to use LINQ then you can go with what K Ivanov posted.

Comment: Note: Sort() "performs an unstable sort" while
OrderBy "performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements
are equal, the order of the elements is preserved"

Comment: How does this work? What is going on there between the curly braces and how am I able to return a var? What is it returning to? Will the code inside the curly braces run once or many times?

Comment: The code in the curly braces is the body to the lambda expression, which is the same as the lambda expression you use in the question.  The problem is that to do this I needed more than 1 statement, so I had to put braces around the body.  Basically the code in there is the comparison code and the sort algorithm will call it many times (on the order of:  nlogn   ).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one preferred way of sorting your Song `class`, you should implement `IComparable` and/or `IComparable<Song>`:

```cs
List<Song> songs = GetSongs();
songs.Sort(); // Sorts the current list with the Comparable logic
```

If you have multiple ways how you want to store your list, `IEqualityComparer<T>` is the interface you would like to implement. Then you can provide that comparer as argument in `List<T>Sort()`.