# How to order a list by one property after ordering it by a different one?

Tags: c#

How can I lexicographically order a list of strings after ordering it by the number of vowels?

Here is the code for sorting the list of string by their number of vowels:

```cs
        private void sortList()
        {
            List<words> wordsList = new List<words>();
            words word = new words();
            word.name = "word";
            word.vowels = 1;
            wordsList.Add(word);

            word = new words();
            word.name = "wood";
            word.vowels = 2;
            wordsList.Add(word);

            word = new words();
            word.name = "grass";
            word.vowels = 1;
            wordsList.Add(word);

            List<words> sortedList = wordsList.OrderBy(o => o.vowels).ToList();

            foreach (words w in sortedList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(w.name);
            }
        }

        public class words
        {
            public string name;
            public int vowels;
        }
```

After it, how can I lexicographically sort the strings with same number of vowels?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works but is asking for a better way to do it. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: I did not know how to lexicographically sort the strings with same number of vowels and I thought there is a way of doing the vowels sorting and lexicographically sorting at once, eventually without using another class. (if only using it is not a good idea)

Comment: "Best" is subjective, and even "better" is vague. We might write code that's easy to read and test, knowing that it could be faster, but that the time saved is trivial. But in another context performance could be critical.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875737/how-can-i-sort-a-listt-by-multiple-t-attributes is the appropriate duplicate for your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add lexicographic sorting after the vowel count sorting, you can use the [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby) extension method, and sort by the `name` field. The code below says, *"first order by the `vowels` property, and then, for all words that have the same vowel count, order by the `name` property"*:

```
List<words> sortedList = wordsList
    .OrderBy(wrd => wrd.vowels)
    .ThenBy(wrd => wrd.name)
    .ToList();
```